# How to make an int array/list property?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Maybe the question is dumb, but (appart of IntVectorProperty) I didn't found anything in the API, so I was wondering about the best way to make a simple list/array.

I tried:

```
my_list_of_ints:CollectionProperty(type=IntProperty)
```

But says it cannot be registered.

`IntVectorProperty` is not useful in my case since I need the list to be dynamic (API says that the vector must be of a predefined size).

So I was wondering about the best approach of making that list of ints.

Edit: the context is to have that array/list of ints inside a class that inherits PropertyGroup.

```
class ObjectA(PropertyGroup):
    int_list:list[int] # This gives error (says property dont exist when I access it)
    int_list:list[int] = [] # This dont give an error, but the data is not saved
    int_list:IntVectorProperty() # I cant use that since the vector is not dynamic
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: What's the context? What is the property for? Operator? Data-block?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys a data block (I want the list to be saved with the file (like others bpy.props))

Comment: Just assign it a value: `bpy.context.scene["someProperty"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys thank you so much! I didn't know that was possible. In my case (sorry for not explaining it properly, I'm a bit of a newbie with add-ons) I want that every instance in a Collection Property (from a Property Group) have it's own array. Do you know if that would be possible? (I think I may could do something similar; my_object["my_array"] = [1,2,3,4...], but in that case would it be saved with the blend file?

Comment: They are supposed to be saved as custom properties, so yes, any data block properties should be saved with the file. It should be easy to test as well, just save, reopen and check.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys really? :o I don't know why, bu I thought that only properties from bpy.props were serialized in the file. Thank you so much for the help friend, much appreciated!

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Just tried it and it doesn't work. If you add a property to to the class, like "an_int_list:list[int]", Blender complaints that it doesnt exist. If you initialize it "an_int_list:list[int]=[]", it doesnt complaints anymore, but dont save its value when saving the blend file (or maybe it saves it, but then when is executes, calls [] and is empty again).

Do you know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What class are you talking about? I add a custom property to the active scene in the example. It does get saved with the file. You can add it to your collection instance object as well, or any other data block in a .blend file.  If you define a Python class in a script, that class exists only when the script is run. If you want to save data to your file, you need to attach it to some data block and data blocks do get saved in the file.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Excuse me for the cunfusion,. I meant that the int_list property must be inside a class that derives from PropertyGroup, not on the scene (the 4th comment)
I added some context in the question.

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to do and how you are trying to that. You should either post the code in full and describe your situation and its context in full if you want to get help, or follow [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html) on your own.  If you define a property group, assign a value to some properties, that code defining the group needs to run when you reopen the file, then you can retrieve the values saved. This is supposed to be in enabled addon. Or you could just store data without property groups in custom properties.

Comment: Sorry, but without full code and context it's really impossible to guess how to help you.

Comment: was added to the original question, but is ok. I appreciated mate :) I think is simply not possible

Comment: Just to be clear, you have not provided full code or context. It's just a definition of a class there. There is no way to know what code you actually run. If you form questions with this little information, you will never get meaningful help.

Comment: The question is likely not dumb and there is probably an answer to it, it's just that you have never actually communicated the question. :/

Comment: ._. Okay mate. But, there is literally nothing more that I could add about the context, since I'm not doing, literally, anything more related the question, since I'm stuck in that thing I'm asking; just adding/defining a list of ints as a property that could be modified and saved.

The only thing I could add is how I did things before asking the question (I had a StringProperty were I added the ints as strings separated by an special character. But I thought "this is totally ugly, there must be a better way XD"

 I mean, the problem is right in the definition of the property.

Comment: PS: I hope I didnt say anything that offended you or anything mate (to be honest, It got me thinking ._. (I TRULY value everyone that makes effort (as you did!) to help others and I dont take that for granted (never!))

PS2: I guess the only thing to solve the problem is simply using a CollectionProperty with a PropertyGroup that has just and IntProperty. Is not a list, and working with them is not as handy, but solves the problem, I guess

Comment: And again, just to be clear, I appreciate/appreciated your will to help mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CollectionProperty is what you need. First define your integer property class like so:

```
class MyIntProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="")
    value: bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)
```

and register it:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(MyIntProp)
```

then define you collection:

```
my_array: CollectionProperty(type=MyIntProp)
```

now you can add elements to it:

```
first = self.my_array.add()
first.name = "first"
first.value = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!